# Django Test: Test view without creating client

Tags: python, django, django-unittest

I would like to write a test case like:

```
    # Create fake request with missing header that we are testing for
    request = HttpRequest() 
    request.META = {}
    response = MyApp.views.start(request)
    self.assertEqual(400, response.status_code, "Unexpected response code")
```

When I run the above code I see the following error message:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'views'

I am a Python newbie and am clearly doing this wrong. Can anyone point how what the error is?

Thanks.
-Raj

Comment: As an aside, if you need to extend your fake request further, you might find [RequestFactory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/advanced/#module-django.test.client) useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown your imports, or included the full traceback, which makes it harder to work out what's going wrong.

Changing

```
import myapp
```

to

```
import myapp.views
```

might work.

Comment: Import myapp.views it was!